# Cannot get distinct values using a SelectListitem

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get distinct values for a dropdownlist, but when using the following syntax, it brings me back all the rows.

Can someone please inform me how to get a distinct value set with the correct syntax?

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ldidList = _db.TrafficHits.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.ldid
            }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Distinct what, value or text? Or both?

Comment: I only needed one field, so I left out the Value property...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that `Distinct` will use the default comparer for `SelectListItem`. You will need to provide a custom comparer like this:-

```
public class SelectListItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<SelectListItem>
    {
        public bool Equals(SelectListItem x, SelectListItem y)
        {
            return x.Text == y.Text && x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(SelectListItem  item)
        {
            int hashText = item.Text == null ? 0 : item.Text.GetHashCode();
            int hashValue = item.Value == null ? 0 : item.Value.GetHashCode();
            return hashText ^ hashValue;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:-

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ldidList = _db.TrafficHits.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.ldid
            }).Distinct(new SelectListItemComparer());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the group by, then you select the first element per group :

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ldidList = _db.TrafficHits
                                          .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
                                          .Select(g => g.First())
                                          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                          {
                                             Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                             Text = c.ldid
                                         });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure `SelectListItem` does not have value equality (i.e. it does not override `Equals`).  Each will be equated by *reference*, so none of your items will be equal even if they have the same values.

Making the assumption that your 'hits' are unique by `Id`, try:

```
var items = _db.TrafficHits
    .GroupBy(h => h.Id)
    .Select(g => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = g.Key.ToString(),
        Text = g.First().ldid
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) Nuget package.

It has a `DistinctBy` method

you can use it like below

```
_db.TrafficHits.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.ldid
            }).DistinctBy(it=>it.Value);
```