# LINQ query to return duplicated in list not working

Tags: c#, linq

I am not sure why but the below code and LINQ statements are returning 0 items and I cannot figure out why. There should be 3 duplicate entries....

```
List<SelectListItem> allClientUserAndCandidateViews = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var clientUserView in clientUserViews)
            {
                SelectListItem item =
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = clientUserView.ClientViewId.ToString(),
                        Text = clientUserView.Name                        
                    };
                allClientUserAndCandidateViews.Add(item);
            }

    List<SelectListItem> matchingClientUserAndCandidateViews = allClientUserAndCandidateViews
          .GroupBy(x => x)
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .Select(y => y.Key)
          .ToList();

     List<SelectListItem> matchClientUserAndCandidateViews = allClientUserAndCandidateViews
          .GroupBy(x => x)               
          .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())   
          .SelectMany(g => g)           
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Are you meaning to `GroupBy` x? Isnt x a "SelectedItem" class, and therefore there would never be more than one item in the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that `SelectListItem` is using default implementation for `GetHashCode` and `Equals` ([source](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/src/System.Web.WebPages/Html/SelectListItem.cs)), meaning that all groups on `(x => x)` will have exactly one item.

Since `SelectListItem` is outside your code, work around the problem by grouping by value and text instead:

```
List<SelectListItem> matchingClientUserAndCandidateViews = allClientUserAndCandidateViews
      .GroupBy(x => new {x.Value, x.Text})
      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
      .Select(y => y.First())
      .ToList();

 List<SelectListItem> matchClientUserAndCandidateViews = allClientUserAndCandidateViews
      .GroupBy(x => new {x.Value, x.Text})               
      .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())   
      .SelectMany(g => g)           
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Note that `GroupBy` also has [an overload which takes IEqualityComparer<TKey>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.110).aspx) as parameter

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Sure, that's another viable approach. However, this one is a lot more expedient, because it does not require creation of a new class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you so much. I was having a very difficult time with this one and had looked through a million SO posts to come up the the incorrect LINQ statement I was using. LINQ confuses me as a junior dev :(

Answer (score 0):

If the `SelectListItem` in your code is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx), then the problem is related to treating all elements as distinct ones, as Distinct uses a default comparer which does not properly compare all the properties.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29988945/2780791) for a full solution:

```
public class SelectListItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<SelectListItem>
{
    public bool Equals(SelectListItem x, SelectListItem y)
    {
        return x.Text == y.Text && x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SelectListItem  item)
    {
        int hashText = item.Text == null ? 0 : item.Text.GetHashCode();
        int hashValue = item.Value == null ? 0 : item.Value.GetHashCode();
        return hashText ^ hashValue;
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would make a clear separation between application logic (computing distinct items) and view logic (view models such as `SelectListItem`). Particularly, you could define some `ItemServiceModel` to hold relevant data, compute the distinct items and them map to `SelectListItem`s.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GroupBy` you need to `GroupBy(x=> x.Value)` or `GroupBy(x=>x.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for getting the grouping and counting, this should work for you.

```
var countByGroups = allClientUserAndCandidateViews.GroupBy(x => x.Text, (key, values) => new { key, Count = values.Count() });
```

Also you can use LinqPad to see what the results of your groupings are by calling Dump method.  Copy Paste this in LinqPad.

```
void Main()
{
    var clientUserViews = new List<Test>();
    var t1 = new Test()
    { 
        Text = "A", 
        Value = "A"
    };
    var t2 = new Test()
    {
        Text = "A",
        Value = "A"
    };
    var t3 = new Test()
    {
        Text = "A",
        Value = "A"
    };

    clientUserViews.Add(t1);
    clientUserViews.Add(t2);
    clientUserViews.Add(t3);
    List<Test> allClientUserAndCandidateViews = new List<Test>();
    foreach (var clientUserView in clientUserViews)
    {
        Test item =
            new Test
            {
                Value = clientUserView.Value.ToString(),
                Text = clientUserView.Text
            };
        allClientUserAndCandidateViews.Add(item);
    }

    allClientUserAndCandidateViews.Dump("allClientUserAndCandidateViews");

    allClientUserAndCandidateViews.GroupBy(x => x.Text, (key, values) => new { key, Count = values.Count() }).Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Test
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```