# Distinct() Select() changes the type in SelectList .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

This kind of a bizarre issue and I can't figure out a solution. I'm using .net core 2.1 and the latest version of EF. I have an orders viewmodel like this:

```
public class OrdersFilterViewModel
{
    public int? AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Account Numbers:")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

If I do a generic database context, there is no problems. However, I get duplicate account numbers in my SelectList. So, if I try to do a do a `Select().Distinct()` to eliminate duplicates:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> FilterOrders(int? account)
{
    var accountContext = _context.Order
        .Where(m => m.UserID == userId)
        .Select(m => m.AccountNumber)
        .Distinct();

    var vm = new OrdersFilterViewModel
    {
        ...
        AccountNumbers = new SelectList(await accountContext.ToListAsync(), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account),
    }
```

Or I try this:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> FilterOrders(int? account)
{
     var accountContext = _context.Order
          .Where(m => m.UserID == userId);

      var vm = new OrdersFilterViewModel
      {
          ...
          AccountNumbers = new SelectList(await accountContext.Select(m => m.AccountNumber).Distinct().ToListAsync(), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account),
      }
```

No matter what I try, including removing the await and doing something like this:

```
AccountNumbers = new SelectList(accountContext, "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account).Distinct().ToList(),
```

There are no errors, but it continually changes my type from `[0] = {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem}` to `Data = {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}` (which I can see when debugging) and therefore bombs when going to the view with:

```
GET https://localhost:44380/orders/filterorders?account=464402 500
send @ jquery.js:9600
ajax @ jquery.js:9206
(anonymous) @ Orders?account=464402:546
dispatch @ jquery.js:5183
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4991
Orders?account=464402:563 Dynamic content load failed.
```

However, the issue doesn't seem to be with the `Distinct()` call, but then gives me distinct order ids, and not distinct account numbers. The issue appears to be with the `Select()` call.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** I created `AccountNumbers` and `AccountNumbers2` `SelectList`s. Both are exactly the same as above except `AccountNumbers2` has `Select(m => m.AccountNumber)` I even removed the `userId` portion for the moment. So, at the most bare essentials of my issue:

```
var accountContext = _context.Account;
var accountContext2 = _context.Account.Select(m => m.AccountNumber);

...

AccountNumbers = new SelectList(await accountContext.Distinct().ToListAsync(), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account),
AccountNumbers2 = new SelectList(await accountContext2.Distinct().ToListAsync(), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", account),
```

AccountNumbers:
[image]

AccountNumbers2:
[image]

Comment: If you put `var bob = await accountContext.Select(m => m.AccountNumber).Distinct().ToListAsync()` on its own line, what is the `Type` of `bob`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changes my type"? Changes the type of what, exactly? Note that your two different versions do *very* different things - one creates a `SelectList` of `SelectListItem` elements wrapping distinct entries, another creates a `SelectList` and then tries to take distinct `SelectListItem` elements.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, Jon Skeet! What an honor! Sorry, my terminology is lacking on this stuff... so try to read my mind, I'll do my best. When I debug and break at `return PartialView("_FilterOrders", vm)` When I hover over `vm` I can see I no longer have individual `SelectListItem`s, but has changed to `ListDictionaryInternal` and I then have to drill down to see my individual results which are never 'SelectListItem`s. Hopefully, that makes sense?

Comment: Well they should still be `SelectListItem` values, otherwise it wouldn't be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (they could be instances of a subclass of SelectListItem of course)

Comment: @JonSkeet  Hmmmm, to add more clarity... If I hover over `vm`, `AccountNumbers` is still a `SelectList`. When I expand `AccountNumbers` and go down and expand `Results View` (so 3 levels deep in those VS popups), that's where I see my `SelectListItem`s have changed to `ListDictionaryInternal` and I now noticed a `Message` `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I'm trying to update the question with some screenshots, but forget the keyboard shortcuts to capture those popup menus before they disappear...

Comment: @mjwills Sorry for the delay... Yes, it's `(local variable) List<int> bob` I added an update to the question too. Hopefully, it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use select you define what you want returned

```
Select(m => m.AccountNumber)
```

This would return a list of the AccountNumber column only.

Comment: Ok, so then what do I use to define distinct `SelectListItem`s? I guess you answered my question as to what I'm doing wrong, but was hoping for a solution too. :)

Comment: @SumNone: Well presumably *after* the Distinct call, you'd want `Select(n => new SelectListItem { Value = n })`. But I'd expect your first version to work, creating a `SelectList` from the values. But it's not clear what you saw with each version (I'd expect them to be different).

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, thanks for the thoughts. I stripped everything down to the bare essentials and added an update to my question with screenshots so you can  better see what I'm seeing. Hopefully it helps clarify my issue.

Comment: @SumNone: Okay, it looks like part of the problem is that your new `SelectList` is looking for an `AccountNumber` property *inside* the account number - that's what the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` parts are about. If the value *is* just the account number, that's not going to work. I don't know much about `SelectList`, but you could try passing "." for the second and third arguments to the `SelectList` constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet I definitely see what you're saying now (despite being in your answer the whole time)... I tried the "." and no go, but was worth a try... I did find something that works and added an answer. Many thanks for your help, not just for this one, but the countless other answers and comments I've read from you (including your blog). If it weren't for guys like you, guys like me (who usually learn from example rather than text books) would be dead in the water. Best regards...

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of keeping my project moving...

First, I removed any reference of `Select(m => m.AccountNumber)` and `Distinct()` and did the following instead:

```
AccountNumbers = new SelectList(await accountContext.ToListAsync(), "AccountNumber", "AccountNumber", magic)
.GroupBy(x => x.Text).Select(x => x.First()).ToList(),
```

I got the idea from [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1957574.aspx?selecting%20distinct%20items%20from%20the%20selectlist%20). It appears there are more [elaborate things you can do with Distinct()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29988945/2300177) that I might try later. Anyway, I'm definitely open to other answers/criticism and have added a `TODO` to revisit this one later...